# Multiple `login` endpoints for `Flask-User`?

Tags: python, flask, user-management

I'm working on a Flask app that needs user management. However, I have multiple parts of my site, let's call them `/site/<name>/` with each of them having their own users (linked in the DB to `name`).

So, what I want to achieve is:

1. Any unauthorised access to anything `/site/<name>/<path>` gets redirected to `/site/<name>/login` (so, I cannot simply redefine `login_view_function`).
2. When the user logs in, the argument `name` is also used (so, a user from `/site/name1/` cannot log in at `/site/name2/`).
3. A login from `/site/name1/login` works inside `/site/name1/<path>`, but not in `/site/name2/<path>` (the user is unauthorised there; can also get logged out of `name1`... I don't particularly care what exactly happens).
4. Whatever happens outside of `/site/<name>/` (or for invalid `name`) is irrelevant for now.

I tried redefining URL rules in a `before_request` decorated function:

```py
site_manager = UserManager(db_adapter, app)
...
@app.before_request
def config_flask_user():
    m = re.match(r'https?://[^/]+/site/(?P<name>[^:/]*)', request.url)
    if m:
        name = m.group('name')
        flask.g.app_theme = name
        if not name_ok(name):
            flask.abort(404)
        # Make a no-arguments node for the current site
        app.debug = False
        app.add_url_rule(
            '/site/%s/' % name,
            'site.current',
            site,
            methods=['GET', 'POST'],
            defaults={'name': name},
        )
        app.debug = DEBUG
        # Use it as the post-logout endpoint, so that it leads to a page
        # where re-login works properly
        site_manager.after_logout_endpoint = 'site.current'
        # Override existing `login_url` and `logout_url` routes, to fit
        # the current site path
        for action in ('login', 'logout'):
            rule = '/site/%s/%s/' % (name, action)
            endpoint = getattr(site_manager, action + "_url")
            view_func = getattr(site_manager, action + "_view_function")
            for r in app.url_map._rules:
                if r.rule == endpoint:
                    print("Redefining rule", endpoint, "as", rule)
                    r.rule = rule
                    r.refresh()
```

This seemed to work fine, but it actually breaks if the server is restarted between loading the Login page and actually submitting user's login and password, seemingly due to that spot being too late to redefine these paths, and I'm worried that it's the wrong approach (maybe it can cause collisions between different requests to different "sites"?), especially for the intended multi-worker environment.

**TL;DR:** How to get `/site/<name>/` paths to have `Flask-User` login dependent on the `name` argument?

Comment: Use term "user session". If user is logged in on /site/x/ then a session for the whole domain is created. There are two variants: use single session for all /site/<name> endpoint and have site<--->user mapping in it, or use different session for each /site/<name> (for example each endpoint uses different cookie).

Comment: @Chikiro Thanks, but that doesn't resolve #1, i.e., different login endpoints (with different page designs). Once I'm logged in, it's fairly simple to know where. It's the parts before the login that I'm confused with.

Comment: Try unauthorized_handler https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.unauthorized_handler It can be programmed to redirect to any url. It's better to create something like current_site or add detected site to request context using before_request. And then use it to redirect unauthorized users to url. I think you need to create special route for custom login page/pages.